# How to download code using TortoiseHg (Mercurial)

Tags: svn, tortoisehg, stackexchange-api

I am trying to download the code  [theworldsworststackoverflowclone](http://code.google.com/p/theworldsworststackoverflowclone/source/checkout). At first I have tried with Tortoise SVN but later get to know that hg command is not supported.

Now I downloaded [Mrcurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/) and TortoiseHg 2.0.2 with [Mercurial 1.8.1 - x64 Windows](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/) and installed on my system. I have also tweaked the proxy settings required.

But whenever I am trying to clone , then I am getting the following error:

```
Clone not found [Command returned Code 225]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me. I'm using TortoiseHg (1.1.5) and Mercurial (1.7)

My Steps:

1. Right Click and select TortoiseHG
2. Select Clone ...
3. In the dialog that pops up I put Source Path: https://theworldsworststackoverflowclone.googlecode.com/hg/
   and Dest Path: theworldsworststackoverflowclone

Comment: Thanx , Was Providing the Destination Path Wrong