# How to download this google code with Tortose SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, google-code, wmd, wmd-editor

I am trying to download http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ from google code.

Having not done this before, have installed Tortoise SVN and tried various addresses to `SVN Checkout`.

Addresses I have tried that have resulted in a (405 method not allowed)
https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/
http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/
http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/hg

How can I find out which address I should be using?

Also, I am logged into the site as I have a gmail with google.

(Hopefully I have found the correct WMD editor too). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the source is using a mercurial repository not a subversion one ... 
install tortoisehg ( http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/ ) and then use the url provided ( https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ ).

For new mercurial users you should read Joel's great article on http://hginit.com/

Cheers!

Comment: forgot about that article completely; it's a very nice read, written to be user-friendly

Comment: This SO helped me too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307770/how-to-download-code-using-tortoisehg-mercurial

Answer (score 2):

This project uses mercurial, not subversion, for version control; you're using the wrong program to download it, as tortoise svn is for subversion. You can try using [Tortoise hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm frankly not even sure this particular project actually uses Subversion - I couldn't tell for sure.

But assuming it does, you can answer most of your Subversion questions here:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ

In particular, you can do an anonymous SVN checkout like this:

> http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_check_out_code_anonymously?
>
> You can use a Subversion client to check out a project's "trunk" code
>   by requesting this URL: http://projectname.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

PS:
All the project page talks about is "Mercurial".

"Tortoise" supports several version control protocols: CVS, SVN ... and Mercurial:

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialFAQ